# c# Auto print PDF from document library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, web-services, pdf, sharepoint, printing

***My task:*** 
Build a window service (build a C# console app beforehead) to auto print using the default printer any PDF files added to a specific document library in SharePoint.

I found codes for printing PDF from the local directory but have problem in the SharePoint part.

I am new to c# and SharePoint programming and I do not know where to start from. Any help would appreciate!

**Problem:**

1. Should I directly get files from SharePoint or download it to local pc (and delete it after print job) before doing the printing part?
2. If I am to get file directly from SharePoint, I tried to apply the following codes with namespace: *using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;* and *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll* in the lib of the current pj but get error.

   `using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
       {
          using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
            SPFile file = web.GetFile(url);
          }
        }`

*Error: The type of namespace name SPSite/SPFile/SPWeb could not be found*.

3. All in all what skills/methods should I use in tackling the task?

   - Auto monitor a SharePoint doucment
   - Retrieve the PDF file
   - Print the PDF

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it is better to get files from SP.
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll is used for client side object model, your code is server side (works only on SP server). For server side use `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint` namespace.
3. Use event listeners for monitoring: documents added/edited.  Retrieve PDF from SP and print it, as you said you ar able to do that.

Comment: I tried to find Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions but I couldn't.(Does it implies WSS is not installed? Mine is not a server?) Actually how do I determine to use client-side or server-side code? ps the sharepoint site im working says its sharepoint server 2013, does this matter? Thanks!